# Basement room + concrete foundation + drywall + moisture question

Tags: drywall, basement, mold, moisture

Basement + concrete foundation + drywall / moisture question: just got drywall glued to a small portion of concrete foundation in an unfinished basement room:

[image]

Should I have contractor remove these drywall pieces to prevent any moisture/mold issues?

House is 2 years old and left 1 unfinished basement room by the garage undone. Trying to complete it.

Thank you!
JJ

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do the "X"s indicate?

Comment: Those Xs are the foundation concrete that was covered in drywall w glue and concrete nail

Comment: So the picture is earlier than the work that you're asking about?

Comment: Added a 2nd photo